# Rigid body objects exploding

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body simulation where all the Suzanne heads are exploding outwards and going through a solid object and I can't really find out why. I am using blender version 2.8, any help would be appreciated. 
I want the Suzanne heads to pour out of the box into the bowl. The box is animated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

these are the Suzanne head settings
[image]

Comment: What did you use to make the suzanne heads explode?

Comment: I did use anything, I didn't do it on purpose. They should just fall into the box but they explode instead.

Comment: May i ask you to add some more details like what you want to do, as i thought all suzsanne heads where supposed to be in the box to start with, supposed to wait for something. In that case starting them deactivated may help. But now i read they should fall in the box. So to help others help you, i suggest to add more details, and maybe even the .blend file, as that could allow easier understanding too.

Comment: I'm currently having problems uploading the .blend file but I will upload it as soon as I can get it to work. And to clarify, they start in the box but they should "settle" in the box before being poured into the bowl.

Comment: I am understanding it that you want the heads to act like cereal, settled into the box, then when you pour them out to be like pouring cereal out of the box. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46458/making-an-object-fall-with-cell-fracture

Comment: Lowering the margin to 0.01 didn't work and neither did 0.005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the issue wasn't with the Suzanne heads but with the box they were in. It's collision was set to Convex_Hull making the box solid all the way through instead of being hollow. Therefor causing the Suzanne heads to fly outwards. Simply changing this setting to Mesh did the trick. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different approach; I set up all the rigid body settings for the object while keeping it at the world origin, after setting it all up I changed its location and it was working (falling down vertically) smoothly. (I kept the object collision shape to convex hull and collision margin to 0, for the active body).

I noticed that setting up the rigid body settings for body by keeping it anywhere away from the world origin resulted in an implicit inertial force maybe that resulted in quick explosion like movement in the object. This occured for me even though convex hull was selected.

So for me keeping the object at world origin first and then moving it anywhere else worked.